# Resource Group Name cannot be Null?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I have a script that suppose to convert 400 vms unmanaged disks into managed disks. Our azure infrastructure is built in such a way that naming conventions almost matches the names of the virutal machine or same how are likely the same, for example if I have a vm named E1PrGrp19VFe01 it resides in E1PrGrp19Rg resource group hence I am using below statement to store the name of the RG inside a variable like below:

```
$VmCode = Read-Host "Partner/VM Code" (Will give a name of the VM)

$Rg = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*$VmCode*"} (this will store the name of the resource group)
```

Problem is when I try to execute $Rg I didnt get anything, after this when I run the for loop to stop all the vms in an RG I get the below error:

```
Stop-AzVM : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ResourceGroupName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:35
+ Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $Rg.ResourceGroupName -Name $Vm.Nam ...
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Stop-AzVM], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.StopAzureVMCommand
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: but if vm is named `E1PrGrp19VFe01` and rg is named `E1PrGrp19Rg` it wont match?

Comment: Thats why I have used a statement as -Like, will it not work there? this surely works when I call $vm after executing the below statement and it gives me correct RG name.  

$Vms = Get-AzureRmVm | Where {$_.Name -like "*$VmCode*"}

Comment: it doesn't work like that. `'ab' -like 'a'` works, not `'a' -like 'ab'`. i mean, isnt it obvious?

Comment: But the $VMs command is able to fetch the resourcegroup name and the vms involving it..

Comment: what can be done in order to achieve this??

Comment: well, what are you passing to the `$vmcode`? the error is likely due to the $rg being empty

Comment: Its the name of the virtual machine, and $rg is trying to insert the value name for the resource group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you, the error shows the message clearly that the resource group is empty. And it's a bad way to get the resource group which the VM in. If the group name is completely different from the VM name, then you cannot get the group name.

I will suggest you use the way below, it gets the group name from the information of the VM:

```
$Rg = (Get-AzVM | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "$VmCode"}).ResourceGroupName
```

Comment: let me try this out

Comment: This indeed worked, but basically its stooping a vm which has been present in the vmcode, and not all the vms inside the resource group.

Comment: @Gang523 Yeah, as you show in the question, you just give a vm name for the VmCode, so it gets one resource group which the vm in. How do you think you can get all the groups just from one VM if the vms do not in the same group?